# Python Pandas Equivalent to Excel Countif

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried different solutions where similar questions where made, but didn't get the expected result, so far.

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, where both of them contain a column named `'fb rq id'`.

There are far more lines in `df2` than in `df1`, and I want to check which values from `df2['fb rq id']` are in `df1['fb rq id']` and how many times it appears there, creating a column on `df2` with the number of times the value on that line is in `df1`.

If you know how to create a column with just binary information wether `df2.['fb rq id']` is in `df1['fb rq id']` , that also helps.

Thank you!!

Comment: "*If you know how to create a column with just binary information wether df2.['fb rq id'] is in df1['fb rq id'] , that also helps.*"  This is `df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])`  and if you put `.sum()`  at the end, you'll get the total number of occurrences.

Comment: Or `df1['rb rq id'].value_counts()[df2['rb rq id']]` may be more efficienct in some cases.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko wouldn't that raise KeyError's for values in df2 but not in df1?

Comment: @ayhan ah you are right

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Maybe something like `df2['rb rq id'].map(df1['rb rq id'].value_counts())`?

Comment: @ayhan I suppose, if value counts are computed once.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
df2['count_from_df1'] = [list(df1['fb rq id']).count(id) 
                         if id in df1['fb rq id'] else 0 
                         for id in df2['fb rq id']]
```